# How to open a .txt.enc file?

Tags: encryption, openssl, file-format

I have a .txt.enc file. When I try to open it in a text editor like Emacs, I get an arbitrary number of characters and numbers. It is encrypted, actually. I also have tried the openssl command line tools, but they don't give the correct result either.

Does anybody know how I can open such a file?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/160253/encrypting-decrypting-a-single-file-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts/160334

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the file is encrypted or encoded somehow, but the obvious question is, how?

If program used to encrypt the file is a fairly common one, and if it includes a known header in its output, then the Unix [`file` command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) might be able to recognize it.  If not, it may come down to guesswork.

Note that the file might not actually be encrypted with a secret key: it seems that the `.enc` extension is sometimes used e.g. for [uuencoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding) files, which are just binary files encoded as ASCII text, very similar to [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding.  The `file` command definitely ought to recognize those, though.

If the file *is* encrypted, though, then even after finding the software used to encrypt it, you'll still have a bigger problem: finding the correct key.  If the encryption is any good, the only way (assuming you don't know the key already) to do that will be to all possible keys by brute force.  *If* the key is based on a password, *and* if the password is fairly weak (i.e. very short and/or common, like "abc123"), it might be possible to find it using a brute-force password cracker.  But I wouldn't hold my breath.

(Of course, if the file is encrypted and you don't know the password, the next obvious question is, how did you end up with the file, anyway?)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I tried file command but I just got:  'xxx.txt.enc: data' . I didn't get to anything helpful...
When I open it in Emacs, the first some characters(also known characters) are : 'Salted__C' . Decrypting this file is part of a course assignment that I'm working on it.  I don't have any other information regarding the method of encryption, its password, etc.  I just have to open it! What can I do? (By the way, we are allowed to use net to solve the assignment :) )

Comment: OK, that definitely looks like the output of `openssl enc`. If that's really all you have, it looks like you're supposed to write (or find, I'm sure this has been done before) a brute force openssl password cracker. I'd start by trying all words in `/usr/share/dict/words`.

Comment: Is there any way to understand the encryption method so that I can apply it when using 'openssl enc'? I mean e.g. whether I should use '-aes-256-cbc' or '-cast5-cbc' or other methods...

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. I didn't see anything obvious about it in the documentation, but maybe looking at the openssl source code could help. Or you could just try all the supported methods, there aren't _that_ many. (Ps. Looks like this question got closed. I voted to migrate it to superuser.com, but it seems the other voters disagreed. Anyway, now that you know it's an openssl file, you might want to try reasking it on http://security.stackexchange.com/ or http://crypto.stackexchange.com/.)

Comment: Elik same problem here. did you find your answer?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the file is encrypted. The original file will be something like xxx.txt and the encoded file is xxx.txt.enc and it has been encoded using some proprietary utility.

You need access to that application which has encoded this file or at least knowledge of what encoding system is used by that application in order to decode it.

Comment: Thanks Murtuza for the answer. but how can I understand that what encoding system and what application has been used to encrypt it?

Comment: To add to Elik's comment, are there some common applications that can be tried on the file on the chance of finding one that can decode it?